# Python accessing modules from package that is distributed over different directories

Tags: python, module, package

I have a question regarding one single module that is distributed over multiple directories.

Let's say I have these two file and directories:

```
~/lib/python
   xxx
      __init__.py
      util
         __init__.py
         module1.py
         module2.py
~/graphics/python
   xxx
      __init__.py
      misc
         __init__.py
         module3.py
         module4.py
```

So then in my Python modules, I did this:

```
import sys
pythonlibpath = '~/lib/python'
if pythonlibpath not in sys.path: sys.path.append(pythonlibpath)
import xxx.util.module1
```

which works.

Now, the problem is that I need xxx.misc.module3, so I did this:

```
import sys
graphicslibpath = '~/graphics/python'
if graphicslibpath not in sys.path: sys.path.append(graphicslibpath)
import xxx.misc.module3
```

but I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named misc.module3
```

It seems like it somehow still remembers that there was a xxx package in ~/lib/python and then tries to find misc.module3 from there.

How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can't without an extreme amount of trickery that pulls one package structure into the other. Python requires that all modules in a package be under a single subdirectory. See the `os` source to learn how it handles `os.path`.

Answer (score 1):

Python does indeed remember that there was a `xxx` package. This is pretty much necessary to achieve acceptable performance, once modules and packages are loaded they are cached. You can see which modules are loaded by looking the the dictionary `sys.modules`.

`sys.modules` is a normal dictionary so you can remove a package from it to force it to be reloaded like below:

```
import sys
print sys.modules
import xml
print sys.modules
del sys.modules['xml']
print sys.modules
```

Notice that after importing the `xml` package it is the dictionary, however it is possible to remove it from that dictionary too. This is a point I make for pedagogical purposes only, **I would not recommend this approach in a real application**. Also if you need to use your `misc` and `util` packages together this would not work so great. If at all possible rearrange your source code structure to better fit the normal Python module loading mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed by Implicit Namespace Packages in Python 3.3.  See [PEP-420](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

Comment: This seems to be the right answer for python 3, though an explanation with a working example would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is an adaptation of an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48833534/865883).

Following up on @Gary's answer, the [PEP 420 page](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) says to use the following code on shared `__init__.py` packages.

`__init__.py`:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

This code should be placed inside the xxx directory's `__init__.py`.
See the *s below

```
someroot/
├── graphics
│   └── python
│       └── xxx
│           ├── ****__init__.py****
│           └── misc
│               ├── __init__.py
│               ├── module3.py
│               └── module4.py
└── lib
    └── python
        └── xxx
            ├── ****__init__.py****
            └── util
                ├── __init__.py
                ├── module1.py
                └── module2.py
```

Some `setup.sh` file to add to the Python Path:

```
libPath=someroot/lib/python/
graphicsPath=someroot/graphics/python/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$libPath:$graphicsPath
```

Python test code (tested on Python versions 2.7.14 and 3.6.4 using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)):

```
import xxx.util.module1
import xxx.misc.module3 # No errors
```