# Split Python source into separate directories?

Tags: python, import, project-organization, pythonpath

Here are some various Python packages my company "foo.com" uses:

```
com.foo.bar.web
com.foo.bar.lib
com.foo.zig.web
com.foo.zig.lib
com.foo.zig.lib.lib1
com.foo.zig.lib.lib2
```

Here's the traditional way to store the source on disk:

```
pysrc/
  com/
    foo/
      bar/
        web/
        lib/
      zig/
        web/
        lib/
          lib1/
          lib2/

PYTHONPATH=pysrc
```

But for organizational purposes (different teams, different revision control, etc.), we want to store these as follows:

```
bar/
  pysrc/
    com/
      foo/
        bar/
          web/
          lib/
zig/
  pysrc/
    com/
      foo/
        zig/
          web/
          lib/
            lib1/
            lib2/

PYTHONPATH=bar/pysrc:zig/pysrc
```

**The question is:**

Are there any issues with this second method of organization?

For example, if we `import com.foo`, where would Python look for the `__init__.py`?

Would symlinking these directories make sense? e.g.:

```
pysrc/
  com/
    foo/
      bar/ -> symlink to /bar/pysrc/com/foo/
      zig/ -> symlink to /zig/pysrc/com/foo/
```

Any general code organizational suggestions are welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python accessing modules from package that is distributed over different directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847146/python-accessing-modules-from-package-that-is-distributed-over-different-director)

Comment: @Ignacio: Thanks, I didn't see that one.  I've added here the question about symlinking, which wasn't discussed in the other one, and seems like a viable solution.

Comment: This works in Python 3.3+, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17202582/851737

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python will go through sys.path in order (which includes PYTHONPATH and then some), looking for a com.foo package in each.  The first one it finds, it will use to the exclusion of others, unlike Perl or Java which effectively merges together package namespaces.  There are things you can do to `__path__` that change this behavior, but "first match wins" is how Python behaves out of the box.

As long as you keep all of com.foo.bar entirely in bar/ and all of com.foo.zig entirely in zig/, you shouldn't have any problems with the second layout.

Answer (score 3):

Reading through the [PEP 420 page](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), it looks like you can add the following `__init__.py` to the shared packages:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

So your directory structure would be as follows (*-marked `__init__.py` files have the above code):

```
myroot/
├── bar
│   └── pysrc
│       └── com
│           ├── ****__init__.py****
│           └── foo
│               ├── ****__init__.py****
│               └── bar
│                   ├── __init__.py
│                   ├── lib
│                   │   ├── __init__.py
│                   │   └── barlib.py
│                   └── web
│                       ├── __init__.py
│                       ├── barweb.py
└── zig
    └── pysrc
        └── com
            ├── ****__init__.py****
            └── foo
                ├── ****__init__.py****
                └── zig
                    ├── __init__.py
                    ├── lib
                    │   ├── __init__.py
                    │   ├── lib1
                    │   │   ├── __init__.py
                    │   │   └── ziblib1.py
                    │   └── lib2
                    │       ├── __init__.py
                    │       └── ziblib2.py
                    └── web
                        ├── __init__.py
                        ├── zigweb.py
```

Set the python path to point to your `com/` directories:

```
barPath=/myroot/bar/pysrc/
zigPath=/myroot/zig/pysrc/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$barPath:$zigPath
```

To test (I tried on 2.7.14 and 3.6.4):

```
from com.foo.bar.web.barweb import BarWeb
from com.foo.zig.web.zigweb import ZigWeb
b = BarWeb()
z = ZigWeb()
```

Not having the `__init__.py` code yields:

```
ImportError: No module named zig.web.zigweb
```